# Need String value when check and unchecked in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a situation where my http response object like this.

```
animal:any = {
    "dog": "true",
    "cat": "false"
  }
```

"`true`" and "`false`" is a string value so `**ngModel**` can't make the `checkbox` checked as per animal object value. And when ever I click the `checkbox` the value is automatically changed to a boolean value like this.

```
{
  "dog": false,
  "cat": "false"
}
```

so, when I send this data by http post the backend can't accept that data. In their backend is running by Laravel. For that properties, there is the enum field. Can anyone give me solution.

**Here is the plunker for visualization**
https://embed.plnkr.co/DQUqFmnSjhtkBy0DeZHI/

Comment: what is the difference between both of these??

Comment: string and boolean value difference. I need string value in my object. Check the plunker.

Comment: checkbox returns a boolean value. so how you can make that to string. Why is that you forcefully need a string?

Comment: I know that check box return boolean. But the backend Laravel guy can't send me the boolean value by enum field.

Comment: Your backend Laravel guy should get an ass whooping.

Comment: string value means you need to get dog or cat right ?

Comment: No, I need string "true" or "false" like this not true or false

Comment: Would append the Boolean value to an empty string `"" + false` help?

Comment: no that's not helped @PraveenM

Comment: To be honest if you are sending a `JSON`, it will be a string object. It's a backend problem that it convert values to Boolean

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert all boolean values in an object to strings, just iterate through the object and that's it:

```
import isBoolean from 'lodash/isBoolean';

const convertBooleanValuesToString = (obj) => {
  const newObj = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    const value = obj[key];
    newObj[key] = isBoolean(value) ? value.toString() : value;
  })
  return newObj;                       
}
```

Please, provide feedback in case I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: did you check the plunker example what I have shared? I need the different solution. please check once carefully. Your loadsh answer is good for other solution.

Comment: You shouldn't do hacks such as this when managing your form's data in NG2. Instead, just convert the data before sending it to Laravel BE with a utility fn as the one I've posted above. Or just tell the BE guy that he should play around with JSON serializer and should support actual boolean instead of the current hacky approach. Not supporting booleans is, well, ridiculous.

Comment: Yes, right I need to talk with BE guy for sending me the boolean value. (Y)